# iOS dismissing keyboard, UILabel malfunction

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uilabel

I'm running into a couple problems in the iOS app I'm developing.

One is dismissing the keyboard: while it works on another two screens, there's one screen where it won't dismiss for some reason:

**Login.m**

```
#import "Login.h"

@interface Login()
@end

@implementation Login

-(void) viewdDidLoad{

     [super viewDidLoad];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];


}

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [_username resignFirstResponder];
    [_password resignFirstResponder];
    [_birth resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

And my second problem is that the UILabel at top the screen won't load despite working in the other screens:

**Login.m**

```
#import "Login.h"

@interface Login()
@end

@implementation Login

-(void) viewdDidLoad{

     [super viewDidLoad];

    _etiqueta = @"Introdueix el teu nom d'usuari, la contrasenya, i la teva data de naixement";
    self.label.text = self.etiqueta;
    self.label.numberOfLines = 4;
    self.label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

}


@end
```

My UILabel is created on the storyboard as well, is IBOutlet and I've made sure that it's properly linked.

Can you help me solve these 2 problems?

Comment: Is dismissKeyboard called at all?

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov: yeah, within UITapGestureRecognizer. I've used the very same code for another two screens and there it works perfectly because once I click outside the UITextField, the keyboard IS dismissed.

Comment: Make sure that your class conforms to the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`...

Comment: The variable self.etiqueta & _etiqueta are different, can you use self.etiqueta and check

Comment: @user2071152: "etiqueta" is an NSString that I load into "label", it being an UILabel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this method of dismiss the keyboard

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

otherwise call the `textDelegate` Method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
 }
```

Comment: The first suggestion did it: guess you need it when you're working with multiple UITextFields. Thank you!

Comment: what the problem on second means uilabel

Comment: yeah, my second problem is that the UILabel won't load the text. It's odd because I've used the same methodology for all of my other screens and it works sans a hitch there.

Comment: did u tried this  _etiqueta = @"Introdueix el teu nom d'usuari, la contrasenya, i la teva data de naixement";
    
    self.label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_etiqueta];

Comment: I've tried right now but to no avail: the label doesn't change. And the name of the viewDidLoad method is correctly written.

Comment: k what is this _etiqueta  is string or somthing

Comment: yeah, it's an NSString.

Comment: use alternate idea , this is try NSString *str = @"Introdueix el teu nom d'usuari, la contrasenya, i la teva data de naixement"; self.label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str];    try this

Comment: k , NSString *str = @"Introdueix el teu nom d'usuari, la contrasenya, i la teva data de naixement"; print in console NSLog(@"the str==%@",str);  try this, if it printed , ur self.label.text is incorrect, k

Answer (score 0):

For multiple text fields you can also try something like this.
You can keep track of the most active textfield and then resign the responder on it.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeField = textField;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeField = nil;
}
```

and then dismiss it in your selector

```
-(void) dismissKeyboard
{
    [self.activeField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

for the UILabel .. i have tried your code and it works fine..