# Resign keybord on UIScrollView touch event

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a `UITextField` and `UIButton` in `UIScrollView`.I want to resign keyboard when user touches outside of `UITextField`. If i implement `UITapGestureRecognizer` then button does not work.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652079/ios-dismissing-keyboard-uilabel-malfunction/23652253#23652253

Comment: What about touches began delegate ?

Comment: It does not get called..

Comment: have u tried the above link

Comment: If you are working on iOS 7 only, `scrollView` has a property `keyboardDismissMode` that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapScroll = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];
    tapScroll.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapScroll];
}
- (void) tapped {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```